# unity script error when adding the Vuforia license

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am an android developer. I started to learn unity and I am very beginner. I decided to develop an AR app with Vuforia but after adding a Vuforia SDK to the unity, I faced with the error and I am not able to add a Vuforia's license to the unity. It ruined my life and took me about three days but it still is not working.I have this Script Error: "This associated Script can not be loaded. Please fix error and blah blah blah". I Run the Script in the MonoDevelop and tried to fix all of the errors. but after solving each error I faced with a new one and finally it wants me to add the license. I read more than 10 tutorials and none of them has mentioned such un error and the scripts work for them properly and thay are capable of adding the licence in the unity environment. Any SOLUTION?

Comment: Which Unity version are you using?

Comment: 5.6 and for the Vuforia 6-2-10.

Answer (score 0):

Try using vuforia-unity-6-2-10 and above download it here https://developer.vuforia.com/home-page

And use Unity 5.6 or above. i tested it here in my computer and it works. hope this helps.

Comment: Actually, I was using these versions. But it did not work for me. I uninstalled the unity and installed the version 5.4 and now it works. It seems a little weird but now the problem is gone. By the way, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Script Error: "This associated Script can not be loaded. Please fix error and blah blah blah"

i have had the same problem. i tryed uninstailing and reinstailing. but that did not work.

i resolved the issue by copying my main code and deleting the file. i then opened a new file through unity. i then pasted my code in.

it worked for me.